# Problema con eventos onClick y onMouseover

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

Tengo un problema con los eventos `onClick` y `onMouseover`. Tengo dos elementos `div` para aplicarles eventos diferentes.

El primer `div` al aplicar un evento `onClick`, quiero que cambie el color del segundo a dorado. Viendo el código no veo dónde me he podido equivocar.

El segundo div al aplicar el evento `onMouseover` quiero que se ponga ese texto en el primer div y no hay forma.

> Gracias por la ayuda. Adjunto el código que llevo hasta el momento.

```js
//Poner div de abajo dorado.
function cambiarColor() {
    var a = document.getElementById('div2');
    a.style.color='gold';            
}
//Introducir en el div de arriba texto.
function aparecerTexto() {
    var x = document.getElementById("div1");
    var texto = 'Texto para que se vea en el div de arriba'
    //No se como ponerlo para que se vea.
}
```

```css
#div1 {
    background-color: cyan; 
    width: 200px; 
    height: 50px;
} 
#div2 {
    background-color: yellow; 
    width: 200px; 
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" onclick="cambiarColor()"></div><br>
<div id="div2" onmouseover="aparecerTexto()" ></div>
```

Comment: Gracias @Merling Samuel Sobalvarro por la edición!!

Comment: Recuerda marcar con un check a la respuesta que te ha servido, saludos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para agregar el color a un elemento tienes que utilizar `style.backgroundColor=`.
En tu función `aparecerTexto`, no estabas asignándole la variable `texto` a tu variable `x` por medio de `innerHTML` insertar el texto en el div, de esta forma funciona correctamente.

```js
            //Poner div de abajo dorado.
            function cambiarColor() {
                var a = document.getElementById('div2');
                a.style.backgroundColor='gold';            
            }
            //Introducir en el div de arriba texto.
            function aparecerTexto() {
                var x = document.getElementById("div1");
                var texto = 'Texto para que se vea en el div de arriba';
                
                x.innerHTML = texto;
                //No se como ponerlo para que se vea.
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            #div1 {
                background-color: cyan; 
                width: 200px; 
                height: 50px;
            } 
            #div2 {
                background-color: yellow; 
                width: 200px; 
                height: 50px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div1" onclick="cambiarColor()"></div><br>
        <div id="div2" onmouseover="aparecerTexto()" ></div>
      
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pero ese texto aparece de saque y a mi lo que me interesa es que aparezca cuando hago onmouseover no nadamas cargue la pagina. El tema del color bien!

Comment: Ahi perdona si que funciona perfecto el onmouseover era mi navegador la cache. Saludos y gracias!!!

Comment: De nada, recuerda si mi respuesta fu de ayuda a resolver tu problema, marcala con la palomita verde, así en caso de que algún compañero tenga el mismo problema sepa cuál fue la solución. Saludos :D

Comment: Luego he hecho un onmouseout para que al salir se vaya y tambien un boton de resetear todo al estado original que sino quedaba pobre. Saludos :D

Answer (score 3):

En primer lugar, estás cambiando la propiedad "color" del div a 'gold', como no tienes ningún contenido en ese div, no te muestra nada, prueba con `background` o `backgroundColor`:

```
a.style.backgroundColor='gold';
a.style.background='gold';
```

En segundo lugar, para insertar **texto** en un elemento, la forma más segura es usando `.innerText`.

Te dejo tu código adaptado para que puedas verlo funcionando

```js
//Poner div de abajo dorado.
function cambiarColor() {
    var a = document.getElementById('div2');
    a.style.background='gold';            
}
//Introducir en el div de arriba texto.
function aparecerTexto() {
    var x = document.getElementById("div1");
    var texto = 'Texto para que se vea en el div de arriba'

    x.innerText = texto;
    //No se como ponerlo para que se vea.
}
```

```css
#div1 {
    background-color: cyan; 
    width: 200px; 
    height: 50px;
} 
#div2 {
    background-color: yellow; 
    width: 200px; 
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" onclick="cambiarColor()"></div><br>
<div id="div2" onmouseover="aparecerTexto()" ></div>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta tambien Fernando!!!

Answer (score 3):

Solo cambia el orden del javascript para que no cargue inicialmente.

```js
                //Poner div de abajo dorado.
                function cambiarColor() {
                    var a = document.getElementById('div2');
                    //a.style.color='gold';            
        a.style.background ='gold';            
                }
                //Introducir en el div de arriba texto.
                function aparecerTexto() {
                    var x = document.getElementById("div1");
                    var texto = 'Texto para que se vea en el div de arriba'
        x.innerHTML = texto;
                }
```

```css
                #div1 {
                    background-color: cyan; 
                    width: 200px; 
                    height: 50px;
                } 
                #div2 {
                    background-color: yellow; 
                    width: 200px; 
                    height: 50px;
                }
```

```html
<div id="div1" onclick="cambiarColor()">1</div><br>
<div id="div2" onmouseover="aparecerTexto()" >2</div>
```

Comment: Me estaba rayando y era por el orden del javascript saludos Raul!

Comment: Un placer ayudarte!